# vb.net SQL checking dates

Tags: sql, vb.net, date

Basically, I have a list of dates in a SQL table with some statistics next to each of them. I want to compare the dates in the table with a certain date I choose. However, my dates in my table are stored as Varchar(50) (and have to be). Apparently I can convert the date in the table into date type but I don't know. Does anyone know how? My current code can be seen below.

```
   If Chosen = "Today" Then
        DateStop = Today.AddDays(-1)
        Dim objCmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Stats where (Date > " & DateStop & ")", objConn)
        MessageBox.Show("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Stats where (Date > " & DateStop.Date & ")")
        ObjDataReader = objCmd.ExecuteReader
        test = ObjDataReader(0)
        MessageBox.Show(test)
    End If
```

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I keep getting the error of no data being present when I know that there definitely are dates in my table before and after the day I am trying.

Comment: Try this "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Stats where (convert(datetime, Date, 101) > " & DateStop & ")"

Comment: @Mitul -- I tried that thanks, but still get the same error.

Comment: it may be easier to debug if you run your sql on the back end.  My guess is there's something wrong with the way you're formatting one of the dates and that's why you're not getting any results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're missing is `objCmd.Read()`. Or you could use `objCmd.ExecuteScalar()` instead of `objCmd.ExecuteReader()`.

```
ObjDataReader = objCmd.ExecuteReader
ObjDataReader.Read()
test = ObjDataReader(0)
MessageBox.Show(test)
```

Or...

```
test = objCmd.ExecuteScalar()
MessageBox.Show(test)
```

(You may still also need the cast or convert functions as others have suggested.)

Comment: Thanks, this was the issue, can't believe I overlooked it! Still working on my date conversion.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Count(*) From Stats where (CAST(Date as DateTime) > " & DateStop & ")"
```

use that for your query

Comment: Thanks for giving me an example. Unfortunately this still gives the error of no data being present.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, can you use stored procedure ?

if you do, you could create a SP with the code you need and add at the beginning of your SP the following command

```
set dateformat 'ymd';
```

I used 'ymd' but you can use other format too.

If you can't look at the T-SQL function [CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You will need the [Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) command.

For example, to convert a string from ISO 8601 standard

```
WHERE Date > CONVERT(datetime, '2006-04-25T15:50:59.997', 126)
```